# Efficient way to "loop" through multidimensional numpy array without a loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional numpy array like this:

```
print(original_array.shape) -> (3, 4, 3)
```

It contains values for a 3D grid in cartesian coordinates (x, y, z) I want to extract and append to a new array. Every point in the grid holds a value. So in the example above I have 3 * 4 * 3 = 36 values in total.
Now the problem is that I have a huge array and using 3 loops and normal python lists is pretty slow. I bet there is a way more efficient solution using some numpy tricks.
Any good ideas?

My working solution using for-loops:

```
new_array = []
for z in range(3):
    for y in range(4):
        for x in range(3):
            new_array.append([original_array[x][y][z][0]])  # this gets the value of every 3D point
```

I would like to structure the extracted data in a line by line fashion like this:

```
"""
x1      y1      z1          val1
x2      y1      z1          val2
x3      y1      z1          val3
x1      y2      z1          val4
x2      y2      z1          val5
x3      y2      z1          val6
x1      y3      z1          val7
x2      y3      z1          val8
x3      y3      z1          val9
x1      y4      z1          val10
x2      y4      z1          val11
x3      y4      z1          val12     
x1      y1      z2          val13
x2      y1      z2          val14
x3      y1      z2          val15   
. . . 
"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
new_array = []
new_array.extend(np.ravel(old_array[:, :, :, 0]))
```

Comment: Why are you keeping the `extend` step?

Comment: I thought a list was expected

Comment: How about `np.ravel(old_array...).tolist()`?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to create is an array with:

- indices of the source element in leftmost columns,
- value of this element in another column,

and as I assume, it should be a *Numpy* array.

To do it, run just the following one-liner:

```
result = np.array([ list(idx) + [j] for idx, j in np.ndenumerate(original_array) ])
```